# Xparts and Yparts Blender 2.63 or 2.72

Tags: rendering

It was looking like dividing by parts, a scene for rendering and reading this,

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.4/Manual/Render/Options

see `Xparts` and `Yparts` but on blender 2.4, but the *interface has changed* I currently have the 2.63 and download the, 2.73 and see but I can not see the menu for Xparts and Yparts, someone can say me if these options are even, and if I could show where.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This change was made in version 2.65, described in the release notes [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.65/Cycles#User_Interaction) under 'User Interaction'. You now have to define the size of the tiles by pixels in the performance panel, instead of defining how many tiles. For example, setting a tile to be 100px x 100px when rendering a 1000px x 1000px image would results in 10 tiles by 10 tiles.

However, I personally like to also have the option to define by the number of tiles, using the old way as you describe. I wrote a small addon which restores this functionality which can be found on github [here](https://github.com/RayMairlot/Restore-Render-Parts), which adds back render parts options at the bottom of the performance panel:

[image]